# Antivirus/Malware scan tools fro Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, malware, antivirus

I suspect that my Ubuntu 18.04 device is infected by a malware or something like that. I have had a fraudulent bank transactions. Can you please help me with the best ways/tools to check if my device is infected by a malware or something like that?

Comment: Not your Ubuntu but the browser you're using might. Check add-ons.

Comment: The add-ons are from Firefox store. I will remove them anyways.

Comment: They're are probably safe if you recognize them, i.e., if you know you actually installed them. The point I was trying to make is that if you find there something you don't remember installing then that's suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Install ClamTK from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Run it to check if there any known infections and set it to scan/update automatically.